# video-js don't work with IE 9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, video-processing

I use video-js player on my website: webplustest.com/videos.html. With Chrome it works correctly, but with IE9 the video does not load and does not play. Why?

Answer (score 1):

add a library 
`<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>`